# Boost multithreading and shared variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, variables, boost, shared

First, I'm sorry if this question is somewhere on here already, but my Google skills seem to be failing me.

Basically, I have a function that should check for any incoming messages at any time. There is also a global variable where it should store this message. (I put this function in a thread)

I want to check for incoming messages using something like:

```
while (global_array[0] != '#') { } // all messages are padded with '#'
```

Sadly, this doesn't seem to be working.

I tried making this '`global_array`' volatile, but then it wouldn't go with the TCP functions I'm using for Receiving.

I really just need this to work.. Please, any help would be appreciated.

Edit: "doesn't seem to be working" -> the variable doesn't seem to be changing 'cause I'm stuck in this loop

Comment: Why dont you use a property instead ? Or is the array you "monitor" not owned by your code?

Comment: Can you expand on 'this doesn't seem to be working'?

Comment: use conditions to signal between threads that something is available, never poll global_array[0]

Answer (score 3):

When communicating between threads you need some form of synchronization. Making a variable `volatile` is **not** a means to indicate that this variable is used between different threads. All it does is to prevent the *compiler* from optimizing accesses to this variable but the CPU won't start reading the content of any memory from any place other than its cache unless you tell it to. That is, using `volatile` just makes your code slower (yes, I know that on some platforms the compiler implementers have chosen to hook `volatile` up with multi-threading primitives but doing so is generally considered a bad idea).

For the purpose you describe you want to use a *condition variable* guarding the access to your shared data:

1. The reading thread locks the mutex protecting concurrent access to your `global_array` and keeps waiting on a condition variable until there is data.
2. The writing thread locks the mutex, puts data into it, unlocks the mutex, and signals the condition variable.

I'd think that [Boost](http://boost.org/) has a class encapsulating similar functionality and I'm sure that code for a queue for communicating between different threads has been posted to Stackoverflow. Searching for "thread communication queue" on Google yields plenty of links to get inspiration from.